# Calculating accuracy for each category in a multi-lable classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification

I need to calculate the accuracy for each category (NOT the overall accuracy) in a multi-lable classification problem. It is easy to find the precision, recall and F-score for each category using `classification_report` from `sckkit-learn` library. There are 13 categories distributed as follows:

```
                   precision    recall  f1-score   support

     Category 1       0.58      0.48      0.53       244
     Category 2       0.91      0.85      0.88       728
     Category 3       0.90      0.92      0.91      1319
     Category 4       0.70      0.55      0.62       533
     Category 5       1.00      0.10      0.18        20
     Category 6       0.94      0.84      0.89      2038
     Category 7       0.83      0.78      0.80      1930
     Category 8       0.85      0.44      0.58       113
     Category 9       0.88      0.87      0.87      1329
     Category 10      0.79      0.54      0.64        61
     Category 11      0.81      0.77      0.79       562
     Category 12      0.71      0.62      0.66       416
     Category 13      0.76      0.60      0.67       500

      micro avg       0.86      0.78      0.82      9793
      macro avg       0.82      0.64      0.69      9793
   weighted avg       0.85      0.78      0.81      9793
    samples avg       0.86      0.82      0.83      9793
```

I know that accuracy can be found as follows:     `Accuracy=(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN)` but finding `TP` and `TN` for this multi-lable classifcation problem was an issue for me.

There is a similar question to this one on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041078/calculating-accuracy-from-precision-recall-f1-score-scikit-learn
but for binary-classification problems only.

Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is this homework? If yes please show what you've tried and explain where you're stuck. In particular do you see what are the gold negative instances (TN+FP) for a given class?

Comment: Typically, TP, TN,... can be found from the confusion matrix. However, in my case, i am getting the following error: ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets

Comment: That's probably because you're trying to apply a function which expects its input to represent binary classification, so it doesn't work with a multiclass input. This is because the classification status (TP,FP,TN,FN) *depends on the class*. For instance the precision and recall scores for class X are calculated by considering X as positive and any other class as negative. With the same principle you can obtain accuracy by class, but it's not very useful: it will always be high since for any class X the majority of the instances are "not X", i.e. TN.